# Scrolling through divs, keeps jumping to top of the page

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

The first click takes the user to the bottom of the box. The second click should take the user to the bottom of *that* box. However, it doesn't. It just jumps to the very top of the browser, and stays there.

How can I fix this?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".box1").click(function() {
        $("body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.box1')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000); 
    });
    $(".box2").click(function() {
        $("body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.box2')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Does it jump to the top and then scroll down to the bottom of `.box2`, or does it remain at the top of the page?

Comment: Remains at the top of the page.

Comment: @TomJulianHume can you show your html ?

Comment: When you click the box, what is the value of `scrollHeight`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".box1, .box2").click(function() {
        $("body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).position().top + this.scrollHeight}, 1000); 
    });
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/TLQq4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this : - add html selector as well

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".box1").click(function() {
        $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.box1')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000); 
    });
    $(".box2").click(function() {
        $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.box2')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    });    
});
```